# Google IMA Flash SDK - Flash ads not firing complete event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on adding pre-roll video adverts to a flash video player using the Google IMA Flash SDK (AS3 version).

I'm testing it with different VAST tags to see how it performs. When using a VAST tag (the Google example tag) with ads with type 'VIDEO' on it everything works great, it fires all the events as expected.

However, when I use a VAST tag that has ads with the type 'FLASH' it doesn't fire some events, most importantly the 'COMPLETE' event.

Have other people had these problems, and how did you get around them?

I've done a bit of reading and the documentation states that for Flash ads it doesn't fire the 'COMPLETE' event, but how am I supposed to know when the video advert has finished, so I can start the video content again?